# Checking multiple comboboxes and textboxes for content

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

I'm trying to check a couple of comboboxes and textboxes if they have anything written or selected in them (via a Button click). Is there a compact solution, so that I don't have to write messy code?
Below is a picture of the interface in question.

[image]

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Are you using Bindings? When you do/need the check - Allowing a button, permanent (e.g. red borders if empty)?

Comment: You can create a method to check the emptiness and checked state for the comboBoxes

Comment: @dba I'm checking when I click a button, before it exports the data to a .txt

Comment: @DieserTBZ Is this WinForms or WPF? In WPF you could bind your Button's Command to a Viewmodel Property, in "plain" winforms you will need to do the "ugly" check in the Click-Eventhandler  - thought you can use Binding in WinForm too - but it's a little bit harder

Comment: @dba I'm using WinForms for this project. Could you link me a video or forum post that shows how to do it? I'm new to c# and haven't programmed anything in quite a while.

Comment: As of Tutorials I'd ask google: "C# Winforms", "C# WPF App", and so on :-) You will find endless resources :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain WinForms:

[image]

You could handle the click-Event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var canExecute =
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text) &&
    this.comboBox1.SelectedItem != null;

  if (canExecute)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Input missing!");
  }

}
}
```